# How to retrieve files from cloud foundry?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I currently have a spring boot web application. The application writes to a file every time the web app is refreshed. Locally I am able to see the files in the root path directory. But when I upload my .jar file to cloud foundry how would I be able to obtain those files that are being written?

**Script snippet writing to file**

```
try{
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
File file = new File(dateFormat.format(date) + "data.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
out.write("Some Data is being written");
out.close;
}
```

I am able to find data.txt in my root folder. But How can I get those files after I package my application to a jar, and push it to cloud foundry.

**Cf push command**

```
 -cf push testapp -p target/webapp.jar
```

Comment: What have you done with you application? what have you attempted? Have you looked at their quick start and tried to apply your own code there?

Comment: There are some [Guides on the official Spring Site](https://spring.io/guides).

Comment: @AshFrench Yes, I have looked at their guides and did many of them. But I just can implement mine in without getting an error when I run the jar file (after i clean package it).

Comment: Okay, my current java files basically outputs some data such as cpu space , memory free %, etc. With spring I created a webpage with thymeleaf and its functional. I am trying to implement my java file that is getting the data on cpu space into my html page. <th:text ${cpuspace} />. But I can't figure out how to put my java files in without getting an error when I run the program. I am in strong belief that I need to add some spring annotations. but how is the question i'm having.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`cf ssh-code` and then:

`scp -P 2222 -o User=cf:<APP_GUID>/0 ssh.<system domain>:/<path>/<file name> <LOCAL_FILE_SYS>`

Thanks,

Chandan